# Name spelling problem in recommendation letter

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter, personal-name

I have applied to several US universities for admission to the PhD program this fall, so I requested my professors to write recommendations for me.

One of the professor wrote my name incorrectly. My full name is: **Md Rohan Hossain**, but the professor wrote **Md. Rahan Hussein**. He already submitted the letter with that incorrect spelling. He completed the recommendation process online.

In this circumstances what can I do? Will it cause a big problem?

Comment: On the list of things to worry about in your life, this should be close to the bottom :-)

Comment: Let me add that it could be a problem for non-academic reference letters as it might signal that you are not an important employee if your employer foes not care about writing xour name correctly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do not worry about this. Just use the letter and ignore the spelling mistake (which most people will consider very minor).

As long as it is clear that this letter was meant for you (which is the case here), you are fine. People will care about the content of the letter, not about really minor spelling mistakes in your name, address, etc.

Comment: I agree with Danny; at the same time I would urge you (Rohan) to double (or triple) check anything that _you_ write; in many fields, attention to detail is considered an important characteristic (and lack of attention, a potential negative mark). For example, your title currently talks about a "recomendation letter"...